# Converting 3D Studio Max 8 scripts to 2011

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I've inherited some older 3DS maxscripts for exporting in 3D StudioMax 8. We'd like to leverage these scripts to be used in 3D StudioMax 2011, but have been unsuccessful. Is there a way to quickly convert or will this require some engineering?

Answer (score 1):

It would require engineering.
You would have to rewrite \ update the non working parts of your scripts unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts must be using features of 3ds Max 8 that are no longer available in 3ds Max 2011? Havok/Reactor comes to my mind as an example. 
If that's the case then it is going to be tough to convert them. Otherwise MAXscript has been very stable over many releases, so a lot of really old code works without problems in new releases.

Answer (score -2):

Actually most of the time maxscripts wouldn't require to be changed between different versions of Max.

Comment: Could any issues running the scripts in 3DS 2011 be derived from hardcoded version information inside the scripts?  The scripts were written for 3DS 8 and have several variable references inside the scripts to that(i.e. 'version=8')

Comment: Yep if they coded those kinds of logic then it could potentially cause issues. To check the version of Max, they should have used MaxVersion() function so searching for that would give you a good starting point. Although the way I would expect the version logic not to be limited to 8, but make it like if it's 8 or beyond, so that it would work on any version of Max, 8 and beyond.